# Emberjs, each block helper advanced

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, template-engine, handlebars.js

This is my flat model:

```
 [
    { id: 1, title: '', body: '' },
    { id: 2, title: '', body: '' },
    { id: 3, title: '', body: '' },
    { id: 4, title: '', body: '' },
    // ...
 ]
```

This is my expected template:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
      <h6>{{! item1 title }}</h6>
      <p>{{! item1 body}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <h6>{{! item2 title}}</h6>
      <p>{{! item2 body}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
      <h6>{{! item3 title }}</h6>
      <p>{{! item3 body}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <h6>{{! item4 title}}</h6>
      <p>{{! item4 body}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
```

What is the ember approach to do this?

A simple each helper won't help because template combines two elements from the model.

Should I change my model, customize an array controller, build a component, write a template helper, or is there a built in solution for this simple problem?

Comment: You probably want an array controller here. Have a look at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Comment: Array controller doesn't help me, this each loop has a twist, if you look at the expected template, it groups two items in one iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your data structure.  I'd still use an ArrayController, but at the same time I'd add a computed property on it that grouped everything up (I'm guessing your pattern is every other).

```
App.FooController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  groupedItems: function(){
    var groups = [],
        group,
        model = this.get('model'),
        len = this.get('length');
    for(var i = 0;i<len;i++){
      if(i%2==0){
        group = [];
        groups.push(group);
      }
      group.push(model[i]);
    }
    return groups;
  }.property('model.[]')
});

{{#each item in groupedItems}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
      <h6>{{ item.firstObject.title }}</h6>
      <p>{{ item.firstObject.body}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <h6>{{item.lastObject.title}}</h6>
      <p>{{item.lastObject.body}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Honestly, there are a slew of ways of grouping them, the point I'm trying to make is grouping would be the simplest.

Comment: what is this 'model.[]' can't i just say model

Comment: searching for grouping i found this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491092/handlebars-template-for-ember-js-objects-grouped-by-two

Comment: oh yeah, same concept.  And no, you can't just say model, if you did it would only update if the  array itself was replaced, not if an item was added/removed from the array (if that's never going to happen, and the model is never going to get replaced, it might be pointless to place either in the computed properties dependencies).